# My node.js/express api is not sending emails via sendgrid when deployed to heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, email, heroku, sendgrid

I have had this app working fine locally. I have deployed it to heroku and now cannot get it to work. More specifically when i submit to the contact form, everything seems to work fine but the email does not turn up, and does not seem to turn up on my sendgrid activity at all.
Ive added the credentials to heroku, ive added the sendgrid add-on on heroku. I can't even see any errors anywhere to give me a clue as to why i am not recieving the emails.

Here are the heroku logs from build to making a single request from a contact form attached to the app:

```
2020-10-07T17:16:03.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-10-07T17:16:04.348666+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-10-07T17:16:04.363907+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-10-07T17:16:05.685986+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-10-07T17:16:05.814303+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2020-10-07T17:16:06.260008+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-10-07T17:16:08.187077+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-10-07T17:16:08.187091+00:00 app[web.1]: > my-heroku-api@1.0.0 start /app
2020-10-07T17:16:08.187091+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2020-10-07T17:16:08.187091+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-10-07T17:16:08.369992+00:00 app[web.1]: this is listening on port 39598
2020-10-07T17:16:09.881100+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-10-07T17:16:34.484799+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/email" host=my-heroku-api.herokuapp.com request_id=75fcc1cc-a4e7-4ab5-8628-8ff81d847bcb fwd="23.106.56.14" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=204 bytes=301 protocol=https
2020-10-07T17:16:36.215440+00:00 app[web.1]: hello
2020-10-07T17:16:36.220749+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/email" host=my-heroku-api.herokuapp.com request_id=a782762e-6ffc-40b5-b94d-3785be2a5def fwd="23.106.56.14" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=502ms status=200 bytes=375 protocol=https
```

This is my app:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const sendGrid = require('@sendgrid/mail');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Control-Type, Authorization');
    next();
});
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('ready to go AGAIN'));
app.post('/email', (req, res, next) => {
    sendGrid.setApiKey(process.env.API_KEY);
    const { name } = req.body;
    const { email } = req.body;
    const { message } = req.body;
    const { phone } = req.body;
    const info = `name: ${name} \n email: ${email} \n message: ${message} \n number: ${phone} `;
    const content = `
        <p>You have a new form enquiry</p>
    <h3>Contact Details </h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Name: ${name}</li>
                <li>Email: ${email}</li> 
                <li>Phone: ${phone}</li>
    </ul>
<p>They said: ${message}</p>
    `

    const msg = {
        from: 'Form Enquiry <info@website.co.uk>',
        to: '<my@email.com>',
        subject: 'a New Contact Form Enquiry',
        text: 'New form enquiry',
        html: content
    }

    sendGrid.send(msg)
        .then(result => {
            console.log("hello");
            res.status(200).json({
                success: true
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('error: ', err);
            res.status(401).json({
                success: false
            });
        })
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log(`this is listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`));
```

And my front end:

```
class Contact extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        message: "",
        name: "",
        email: "",
        phone: "",
        buttonText: "Send message",
        sent: false
    }
}

formSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
        buttonText: "Sending..."
    })
    let data = {
        name: this.state.name,
        message: this.state.message,
        email: this.state.email,
        phone: this.state.phone
    }
    Axios.post('https://my-heroku-api/email', data)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            console.log("its working")
            this.setState({ sent: true }, this.resetForm())
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("this is the error", error)

            this.setState({
                message: "",
                name: "",
                email: "",
                phone: "",
                buttonText: "Send message",
            })
        })
}

resetForm = () => {
    this.setState({
        message: "",
        name: "",
        email: "",
        phone: "",
        buttonText: "Message sent!",
    })
}
```

Which is written in react and tbh i havent touched and has been working fine the whole time so Im assuming its not there? I can't see if i'm missing something obvious but ive been staring at it and trying stuff for hours.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks (:

edit: The emails ive tried to send seem to have showed up in my sendgrid activity however they have not appeared in my email inbox..

Comment: Have you remembered to define the environment variable `API_KEY` in Heroku?

Comment: Yes i've done this. Made that oversight enough times so i always remember now! Adding the Sendgrid add-on added sendgrid user and sendgrid pass variables as well.

Comment: If the e-mails are showing up in your sendgrid activity I think we can reasonably assume that the issue is not on your client or server, but with sendgrid.

Comment: Sendgrid was working fine with it earlier on though. The emails were showing up in the activity and then my inbox almost instantly. Im not sure if there is a setting somewhere in Sendgrid that i need to alter since im now using Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this issue today with Heroku and SendGrid. It could be a Heroku issue because everything worked fine until later on today, and now my builds are failing and still not sending emails.

Comment: Hmmm this didnt occur to me. Would truly love for it to not be my fault. My builds were fine yesterday but are also failing today so might leave it alone for a bit and come back to it after a couple of days. Just annoying as i have a deadline! Any heroku alternative suggestions would be welcome (:

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. Mails were under junk, spam, others for me. I'm not sure whether it could help you, but just sharing my thought :) hope it'd have been resolved already.

Comment: This is probably better suited as a comment, not an answer.